# The multi-part identifier "Table.column" could not be bound on Inner Join

Tags: sql-server

Please, help me.

I have 2 tables: `MainInfo (userName, pw)`& `BasicInfo (userName, birthday, phone)`.
I do an query as follow:

```
SELECT MainInfo.userName, pw, birthday, phone
FROM MainInfo M INNER JOIN BasicInfo B
ON M.userName = B.userName
```

But it throw an error: `The multi-part identifier "MainInfo.userName" could not be bound.` What's wrong? I don't understand! I think about it very much, but still don't know why. Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have aliased your table, use the alias to use TWO PART names for columns. i.e  `[TableAlias].[ColumnName]`

```
SELECT M.userName
      ,M.pw
      ,B.birthday
      ,B.phone
FROM MainInfo M INNER JOIN BasicInfo B
ON M.userName = B.userName
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly. Thank you so much, @M.Ali!